# Plot edges labels from graph

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

Is there a built-in function to add edge labels to a graph in `networkx` library. AFAIK you can set them by using the `nx.set_edge_attributes()` function. But I was wondering if it would be possible to skip this and avoid doing manually if you already has the edge labels info in your graph structure.

For instance, given the following dictionary of dictionaries in which keys are nodes and inner dictionaries are target and edge labels respectively. E.g:

```
z = {'224': {'0': 'a'}, '0': {'217': 'b', '224': 'k'}, '217': {'220': 'c'}, '246': {'10': 'd'}, '10': {'241': 'f', '246': 'l'},
 '241': {'220': 'g'}, '11': {'22': 'p', '23': 'i'}, '22': {'9': 'p'}}
```

In above dictionary '224 will be a node connected to '0' with the label 'a'.

I know I can create a graph using:

```
Z = nx.DiGraph(z)
```

And plotting it using:

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(Z)
nx.draw(Z, pos, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')
```

I tried to add labels manually from z, but could not catch the case when a node is connected to more than one node with its own edge label at least as expected.

What I tried so far was:

```
edge_labels = dict()
for (k, v), e in zip(z.items(), Z.edges()):
    for x, y in v.items():
        edge_labels[e] = {'attr1': y}
```

And then add these labels by:

```
nx.set_edge_attributes(Z, edge_labels)
```

But fails and gives the following wrong output when looking at edges using `Z.edges(data=True)`:

```
Out[38]: OutEdgeDataView([('224', '0', {'attr1': 'a'}), ('0', '217', {'attr1': 'k'}), ('0', '224', {'attr1': 'c'}), ('217', '220', {'attr1': 'd'}), ('246', '10', {'attr1': 'l'}), ('10', '241', {'attr1': 'g'}), ('10', '246', {'attr1': 'i'}), ('241', '220', {'attr1': '8'}), ('11', '22', {}), ('11', '23', {}), ('22', '9', {})])
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

The expected output should looks like:

```
Out[39]: OutEdgeDataView([('224', '0', {'attr1': 'a'}), ('0', '217', {'attr1': 'b'}), ('0', '224', {'attr1': 'k'}), ('217', '220', {'attr1': 'c'}), ('246', '10', {'attr1': 'd'}), ('10', '241', {'attr1': 'f'}), ('10', '246', {'attr1': 'l'}), ('241', '220', {'attr1': 'g'}), ('11', '22', {'attr1': 'p'}), ('11', '23', {'attr1': 'i'}), ('22', '9', {'attr1': 'p'})])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`networkx` has function [draw_networkx_edge_labels](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edge_labels.html), that allows you to draw graph labels. But it is not the base functionality of graphs, so its usage is a bit confusing:

You should firstly create your graph, its nodes and edges. After it, you should create the graph layout and then use it for drawings. Here is the example:

```
import networkx as nx

# Create graph
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from([1,2,3,4,5])
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3),(2,4),(4,5)])
for n in G.nodes:
    G.nodes[n]['label'] = str(n)*5

# Create labels dicts
labels = {
    n: (G.nodes[n]['label']
        if len(list(nx.all_neighbors(G, n))) > 2
        else '')
    for n in G.nodes
}
edge_labels = {e: str(e) for e in G.edges}

# Create graph layout
layout = nx.spring_layout(G)

# Create label edges
edge_labels_pos = nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(
    G,
    layout,
    edge_labels=edge_labels
)

# Draw the graph
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, labels=labels, pos=layout)
```

The result will looks like:

[image]

But don't forget to create layout beforehand and use it everywhere! If you will call layout functions several times, you will get something like it:

[image]